# java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed

Tags: java, sqlite

I cant not do the further process because I get ResultSet closed while running this code. I am adding the value after 15 row of the sqlite database table and I want to find average value of 15 row and that should be store in ArrayList.

Here is the code:-

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully3");
    stmt = c.createStatement();
    rs = stmt
            .executeQuery("SELECT TIME,BID,ASK FROM '" + title + "' ;");
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully 20");
    while (rs.next()) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
        if (i > 15) {
            System.out.println("i am in");
            List<String> stocklist = new ArrayList<String>();
            String main = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            String s[] = main.split(" ", 2);
            String date = s[0];
            String time = s[1];
            stocklist.add(date);
            stocklist.add(time);
            stocklist.add(df.format(rs.getFloat("BID")));
            stocklist.add(df.format(rs.getFloat("ASK")));
            rs1 = stmt
                    .executeQuery("SELECT ASK FROM '" + title + "' ;");
            int j = 1;
            while (rs1.next()) {
                if (j < i) {
                    System.out.println(rs1.getFloat("ASK"));
                    avg = avg + rs1.getFloat("ASK");
                }
                j++;
            }
            rs1.close();

            System.out.println("i am out");
            avg = avg / 15;
            changepercent = ((rs.getFloat("ASK") - avg) / avg) * 100;
            stocklist.add(df.format(changepercent));
            stocklist.add("ETE");
            stocklist.add("HUN");
            stocklist.add("ALU");
            stocklist.add("ETE");
            stocklist.add("HUN");
            stocklist.add("ALU");
            stocklist.add("ETE");
            stocklist.add("HUN");
            hntm.addRow(stocklist);
        }
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    c.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Try creating another statement inside loop of rs1

Comment: You can't use more than one `ResultSet` object simultaneously from the same `Statement`. Getting another one closes the prior one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should not reuse a Statement. When you create a new Query, you need so use a new Statement Object. Replace `rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ASK FROM '" + title + "' ;");` with `rs1=c.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT ASK FROM '" + title + "' ;");`

Comment: You can reuse `Statement` objects. This answer is not correct. The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not the answer for this question, but i was also having problem with `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed`.**

In my case the result from the query was empty and i was using **SQLite**, so the ResultSet returned closed.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

// resultSet closed == didn't find anything
if(resultSet.isClosed())
    return false;
```

I tested using **PostgreSQL** and ResultSet stay open even when query is empty. I didn't expect different behavior from different databases.

If anyone want to check my test: https://gist.github.com/thiagola922/fcd80f0f29b83106304c3b64cf64b2b1

As [@marquis-of-lorne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/marquis-of-lorne) said, a better way to check if the connection still open is using `resultSet.next()`.

Comment: I agree: this certainly not an answer. It is not correct either. `ResultSet.next()` returning `false` is the indication that it didn't find anything. You cannot possibly get `resultSet.isClosed() == true` from this code.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne you are right, `next()` is the right way to do. I actually got `resultSet.isClosed() == true` when using SQLite and `resultSet.isClosed() == false` when using PostgreSQL (cheked today). Updated the answer to be more clear about when i got this exception.