# ResultSet closed after executeQuery

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

My code is:

```
Connection c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/syste/Desktop/Gestione_Box_Cavalli/docs/gestione_scuderia.sqlite"); // driver is already tested is okay
Statement s1 = c1.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = s1.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM cavalli WHERE nome = '" + CB_nome_cavallo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() + "';");
idCavallo = Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString(1));
s1.close();
c1.close();
```

The exception is generated at: `"aggiungiModificaClick(ProprietariCavalli.java:231)"`

Which is the line: `"idCavallo = Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString(1));"`

For some reason it gave me this error and it is strange, because I followed the order and steps correctly... :-( I tried to follow tutorial and seems all okay... I tried to write again the code in one line but seems the same error...

The error log contains:

```
gen 10, 2020 10:05:30 PM proprietari.ProprietariCavalli aggiungiModificaClick
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.27.2.1/org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkOpen(CoreResultSet.java:76)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.27.2.1/org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.markCol(CoreResultSet.java:103)
    at sqlite.jdbc@3.27.2.1/org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:445)
    at Gestione.Box.Cavalli/proprietari.ProprietariCavalli.aggiungiModificaClick(ProprietariCavalli.java:231)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection, you should Google how to prevent this

Comment: perhaps the connection isn't valid to begin with? is the `getConnection()` file path correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728494/java-sql-sqlexception-resultset-closed)

Comment: @Marged yes i know but it's for educational purposes this example, so yes i'll search on Google.

Comment: @kaan yes, file path is correct because i used it before for another connection so the path is correct

Comment: @MohamedSweelam trying to see if it is similiar

Comment: @Simone Same case i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `ResultSet.next` before reading the firs row (which may not exist).

In this case "closed" is as in not open, not as in was open but no longer.

@Marged points out you code is subject to SQL injection. In this case you may get away with it depending upon how the selection model was derived, nevertheless use `PreparedStatement` with a constant string. Also use try-with-resource or the Execute Around idiom to ensure your clean up resources whether or not there is an exception..

Comment: A result set that was just returned from `executeQuery` should be open, but positioned before the first row, even if there is no first row. A result set is only closed after calling `close()` (or after reading the last row when close-on-completion is enabled on the statement, closing a statement or connection, or reexecuting on the statement). Given `next()` should throw on exception when the result set is closed, I guess that the driver uses the wrong message.