# How to execute multiple queries and get them under three resultset in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to create a program which will execute three different queries and their result would be mailed along with the user name in a tabular format. Below is the code I am designing,

```
public class SendNotification {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, AddressException, MessagingException {
        // Database connection details
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
        String user = "localuser";
        String password = "xxxxxx";
        //InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        
        //User Details
        String user1 = "abUser";
        String user2 = "xyUser";
        String user3 = "cvUser";
        
        // SQL queries for each user
        String query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbtest WHERE AUTH = '" +user1+"' AND outdate >= SYSDATE - 7";
        String query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbtest WHERE AUTH = '" +user2+"' AND outdate >= SYSDATE - 7";
        String query3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbtest WHERE AUTH = '" +user3+"' AND outdate >= SYSDATE - 7";
        
        // Create a connection to the database
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        
        // Create a statement and execute each query
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery(query1);
        ResultSet resultSet2 = statement.executeQuery(query2);
        ResultSet resultSet3 = statement.executeQuery(query3);
        
        // Get the results and store them in a table
        Object[][] data = {
            {"User ID", "Document Count"},
            {user1, resultSet1.getInt(1)},
            {user2, resultSet2.getInt(1)},
            {user3, resultSet3.getInt(1)}
        };
        
     // Send an email with the results in tabular format
        String from = "devtest@ugc.local";
        String to = "PBxyz@gmail.com";
        
        String host = "mail.test.vb.xcv";
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("Checked-In Document Counts");
        
        StringBuilder table = new StringBuilder();
        for (Object[] row : data) {
            table.append("<tr><td>").append(row[0]).append("</td><td>").append(row[1]).append("</td></tr>");
        }
        message.setText("<html><body><table>" + table.toString() + "</table></body></html>", "utf-8", "html");
        Transport.send(message);
        
        // Close the statement, result sets, and connection
        resultSet1.close();
        resultSet2.close();
        resultSet3.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
        


}
```

But, I am encountering with the below error everytime.

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: getInt
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:237)
> at com.ura.SendNotification.main(SendTINNotification.java:48)

How shall i proceed to get the desired output?

Comment: Which line of your code represents "line 237"?

Comment: @Reporter- In this line {user1, resultSet1.getInt(1)}. It seems the resultsets are getting closed.

Comment: You need to call next on the resultset. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59689090

Comment: Note that this code has a major security leak (SQL injection), and has resource leaks (not using try-with). If it's anything more than a toy project you might want to look into that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Re-executing `Statement` closes previous `ResultSet`

You said:

> java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset

A `Statement` can produce only one open `ResultSet` at a time. Executing that statement again automatically closes the previous `ResultSet` while producing the successive `ResultSet`.

To quote the Javadoc for `ResultSet` (emphasis mine):

> A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, **re-executed**, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Note the *re-executed* part in that quote.

## Revised code

Here is a complete example app using the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)).

Rather than hard-coding for 3 inputs, soft-code using collections.

Notice how we separate the reporting from the database query. Generally best to maintain such a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). This allows us to escape your problem where you trying to juggle all the result sets at the same time. In this code below we gather the results of each `ResultSet` with a `put` to our `Map`. We return the complete map to the calling code. The calling code then passes that map to a method dedicating to reporting (or to sending emails, as seen in your Question).

By the way, I suggest making a habit of using a `DataSource` to contain your database login credentials. This interface makes your deployment more flexible, with the option to externalize this info outside your codebase.

Notice how we use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to [automatically close](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) each `Connection`, `Statement`, `PreparedStatement`, and `ResultSet`.

```java
package work.basil.example.db;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class ExH2 {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {

        ExH2 app = new ExH2 ( );
        DataSource dataSource = app.obtainDataSource ( );

        app.prepareDatabase ( dataSource );
        List < String > users = List.of ( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" , "Davis" );
        app.populateDatabase ( dataSource , users );
        // app.dumpToConsole ( dataSource );
        Map < String, Integer > countPerUserForCurrentWeek = app.countPerUserForCurrentWeek ( dataSource , users );
        app.report ( countPerUserForCurrentWeek );
    }

    private DataSource obtainDataSource ( ) {
        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource ( );  // An implementation of `javax.sql.DataSource` bundled with H2.
        ds.setURL ( "jdbc:h2:mem:history_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
        ds.setUser ( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword ( "tiger" );
        ds.setDescription ( "An example database showing multiple result sets." );
        return ds;
    }

    private void prepareDatabase ( final DataSource dataSource ) {
        String sql =
                """
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history_
                        (
                            user_ TEXT NOT NULL ,
                            when_ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL ,
                            id_ UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() ,
                            CONSTRAINT history_pkey_ PRIMARY KEY ( id_ )
                        )
                        ;
                        """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ( ) ;
        ) {
            System.out.println ( "INFO - Running `prepareDatabase` method." );
            stmt.executeUpdate ( sql );
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
    }

    private void populateDatabase ( final DataSource dataSource , List < String > users ) {
        String sql = """
                INSERT INTO history_ ( user_ , when_ )
                VALUES ( ? , ?)
                ;
                """;
        try
                (
                        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement ( sql ) ;
                ) {
            for ( String user : users ) {
                int limit = ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 7 , 42 );
                System.out.println ( "user = " + user + " | limit = " + limit );
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ ) {
                    preparedStatement.setString ( 1 , user );
                    preparedStatement.setObject ( 2 , OffsetDateTime.now ( ZoneOffset.UTC ) );
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate ( );
                }
            }

        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
    }

    private void dumpToConsole ( DataSource dataSource ) {
        String sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM history_
                ;
                """;
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement ( sql ) ;
        ) {
//            preparedStatement.setString ( 1, "Carol" );
            try (
                    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery ( )
            ) {
                while ( resultSet.next ( ) ) {  // We expect a single row in each result set, for the count.
                    System.out.println (
                            resultSet.getString ( 1 ) + " | " +
                                    resultSet.getString ( 2 ) + " | " +
                                    resultSet.getString ( 3 ) + " | "
                    );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException ( e );
        }
    }

    private Map < String, Integer > countPerUserForCurrentWeek ( final DataSource dataSource , List < String > users ) {
        Map < String, Integer > map = new HashMap <> ( );
        String sql = """
                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM history_
                WHERE user_ = ?
                AND when_ >= ? 
                AND when_ < ?
                ;
                """;
        try
                (
                        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection ( ) ;
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement ( sql ) ;
                ) {
            OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
            OffsetDateTime weekAgo = now.minusDays ( 7 );
            preparedStatement.setObject ( 2 , weekAgo );
            preparedStatement.setObject ( 3 , now );
            for ( String user : users ) {
                preparedStatement.setString ( 1 , user );
                try ( ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery ( ) ) {
                    if ( resultSet.next ( ) ) {  // We expect a single row in each result set, for the count.
                        int count = resultSet.getInt ( 1 );
                        map.put ( user , count );
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
        return Map.copyOf ( map );
    }

    private void report ( Map < String, Integer > countPerUserForCurrentWeek ) {
        System.out.println ( "countPerUserForCurrentWeek = " + countPerUserForCurrentWeek );
    }
}
```

When run:

```java
user = Alice | limit = 32
user = Bob | limit = 7
user = Carol | limit = 13
user = Davis | limit = 24
countPerUserForCurrentWeek = {Carol=13, Alice=32, Bob=7, Davis=24}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are accessing the resultset from the same statements. This will not work. You can create multiple instances of Statements statement1, 2 and 3. Then you access the resultset from each instance accordingly. At the end close all connections resultsets and statements.